# how to open file with atom-editor in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, putty, atom-editor

i want to use atom editor in terminal.

in GUI environment, i can use atom editor with no problem,

but in terminal, i can't open file with atom editor.

atom editor does not support console-mode?

Comment: Indeed, atom does not support console mode, you can launch atom from a terminal but without a X server, the program can't work.